# How to change xml root namespace with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT mapping and I have a task that need to change the root namespace.

here is my sample xml

```
<ns1:ShipStatusResponse xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/pi/VN/ABC/Invoice/10">
  <httpcode>200</httpcode>
  <httpstatus>OK</httpstatus>
  <httpresult>test</httpresult>
</ns1:ShipStatusResponse>
```

and my expected output xml will is like

```
<ns1:ShipStatusResponse xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/pi/ERP/FICO/Invoice/10">
  <httpcode>200</httpcode>
  <httpstatus>OK</httpstatus>
  <httpresult>test</httpresult>
</ns1:ShipStatusResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want (a) an identity template to copy things unchanged by default, and (b) a rule such as

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:ShipStatusResponse" xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/pi/VN/ABC/Invoice/10">
  <xs:element name="ns1:{local-name()}" namespace="http://test.com/pi/ERP/FICO/Invoice/10">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xs:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You may have some difficulty getting it to use the right namespace prefix, because XSLT 1.0 offers no guarantees about the namespace prefixes used in result documents (there is more said in later versions).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://test.com/pi/VN/ABC/Invoice/10"
xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/pi/ERP/FICO/Invoice/10"
exclude-result-prefixes="old">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- rename root element -->
<xsl:template match="/old:ShipStatusResponse">
  <ns1:ShipStatusResponse>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ns1:ShipStatusResponse>
</xsl:template>

<!-- copy all other elements, without copying namespaces -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there are no attributes in the input XML.